# Euro sign is garbled on some machines

Tags: java, spring, encoding, utf

We have a web application (Java spring mvc project).
Our server returns jsons via REST API.

here is a response example from our QA env:

```
{currency: "EURO", symbol: "€", multiplier: 1}
```

here is the same response from a different enviornment (the Dev):

```
{currency: "EURO", symbol: "�", multiplier: 1}
```

Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: An alternative would be to use "EUR", the standard abbreviation for the Euro, just as "USD" is the standard abbreviation for the US Dollar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so my issue was with the build machine (Jenkins) which is running on ubuntu.
All the envs, that the build machine compiled and deployed our app had the issue.

I had to change the gradle tasks to be compiled with

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = 'Cp1252' }
```

(Since we develop on windows env and thats the default).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's because your browser is painting out the font after all the work has been done to it in the background (on the server).  This means you could have it encoded correctly at some point, but once the browser gets it, it is no longer encoded, and showing a character the browser doesn't understand.

You need to run one more pass with JavaScript on the browser side.  A simple replace on the string with the proper encoding will fix it.

Comment: Is it possible that the server will return it not garbled? like in env #1?

Comment: You're going to have to look at the exact string that's returned.  If you're using the exact same browser and getting different results, that really would be strange.